# Cucumber 6 undefined custom step

Tags: java, regex, spring, cucumber, regular-language

I am upgrading Cucumber version in my project and custom configuration changed between versions 4 and 6.

I've registered a custom keyword for Parameter Type.

Everything works, step passes and the value is generated but **the step is still marked as undefined**.

I use Intellij IDEA and [Cucumber plugin for Java](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7212-cucumber-for-java) Is it a plugin problem or somewhere in y code?

**Cucumber step:**

```
When generate uniqueRandom(5) for test
```

[image]

**Java step:**

```
@When("generate {unique_random} for test")
public void testStep(int randomNumber) {
    log.info(String.valueOf(randomNumber));
}
```

**Parameter Type registry:**

```
@ParameterType(name = "unique_random", value = "uniqueRandom\\([0-9]+\\)")
public Integer randomNumber(String original) {
    return ... // some logic of creation
}
```

**Cucumber version:** 6.8.1

Is it possible from my side to do something with this warning?

Comment: If the test executes, it's a problem in IDEA.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust something in configurations to fix it?

Comment: File a bug report with IDEA.

Comment: Has this been reported?

Comment: I've not. If you don't see any bug reports there related to this issue and resolved I don't think it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with Cucumber API and Cucumber Plugin.

I changed my Parameter Type registration method

from:

```
@ParameterType(name = "unique_random", value = "uniqueRandom\\([0-9]+\\)")
public Integer randomNumber(String original) {
    return ... // some logic of creation
}
```

to

```
@ParameterType(value = "uniqueRandom\\([0-9]+\\)")
public Integer unique_random(String original) {
    return ... // some logic of creation
}
```

This solution is described in the documentation of **@ParameterType.name()**

> Name of the parameter type. This is used as the type name in typed
> expressions. When not provided this will default to the name of the
> annotated method.

The plugin **doesn't resolve the parameter name in the annotation** but as a method name.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with Cucumber API?

Comment: this looks like an IDEA bug, not API. my assumptions were both sides, but it turned out to be a plugin issue.